# How to get size of file in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, file-io

Below is my code. My problem is, my destination file always has a lot more strings than the originating file. Then, inside the for loop, instead of using `i < sizeof more`, I realized that I should use `i < sizeof file2` . Now my problem is, how to get the size of file2?

```
int i = 0;

FILE *file2 = fopen(LOG_FILE_NAME,"r");
wfstream file3 (myfile, ios_base::out);


// char more[1024];
char more[SIZE-OF-file2];


for(i = 0; i < SIZE-OF-file2 ; i++)
{       
    fgets(more, SIZE-OF-file2, file2);
    file3 << more;
}

fclose(file2);
file3.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using GetFileSize(). By reading the size of the file from the filesystem, you will avoid a lot of unnecessary computation. This can also be done with _stat(), or on unix it would just be stat().

Here is the definition:

DWORD WINAPI GetFileSize(
  __in       HANDLE hFile,
  __out_opt  LPDWORD lpFileSizeHigh
);

Doc for GetFileSize:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364955%28VS.85%29.aspx

Alternatively you might want to use _stat()

Doc for stat:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The most basic way is to `fseek` to the end of the file and to use `ftell` to give you the offset. The other (stat) functions also do this, but they're not cross-platform. Of course, if you want your code rot in hell, you could also use [GetFileSize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms890939.aspx).

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
off_t offset = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

*Every time you refer to C as Visual C, or C++ as Visual C++ I die a little.*

Comment: OP wasn't referring to C as Visual C, C++, or visual C++. S/he was actually talking about Visual C++ if you read the question at all. I love C89/C99 just as much as the next guy does, and generally hate windows. Although the most effective way to solve the problem for "Visual C++" is to use the API they provide you with.

As far as "code rotting in hell" goes, try using the preprocessor. That's why it exists.

Comment: ... what the preprocessor ? :)

Comment: The preprocessor is what replaces macros/includes files etc. #include, #define, #ifdef #endif #if, etc are preprocessor directives. You could use it to conditionally call a function based on what platform you're compiling for. i.e. #ifdef WIN32 ... GetFileSize() #endif

Comment: @Tom I'll repeat what Romain's said, in a different context though -- "What The Preprocessor!" Why would you want to use something else when you already have a solution that works everywhere?

Comment: I can't speak for whether OP is reading a large file, but try your method on a 16GB file, then after your nap, tell me why you might want to use my solution of reading the size from the filesystem nodes where it is already stored.